# java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception error when placing applet onto website

Tags: java, html, applet

I'm having trouble getting my applet to run on my website. It's my first time embedding an applet to a website and I have no idea what is going wrong.

I created the .jar file following the following website's instructions:https://eyeasme.com/Shayne/HTML5_APPLETS/

And here is the code for the java applet.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class TicTacToe extends JFrame
{
private JButton button [][] = new JButton [3][1];
private boolean checkerO [][] = new boolean [3][2];
private boolean checkerX [][] = new boolean [3][3];
private JPanel panel;
private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 200;
private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 200;
private int turn = 1;

public TicTacToe()
{
    setTitle ("Tic-Tac-Toe");
    setSize (WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //create and register an event listener with all buttons

    for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
        {
            button [i][j] = new JButton();
            button [i][j].addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
            button [i][j].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 35));
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
        {
            checkerO [i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
        {
            checkerX [i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    //create a panel, work on the layout and add the buttons

    panel = new JPanel();
    GridLayout myLayout = new GridLayout(3,3);
    panel.setLayout(myLayout);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
        {
            panel.add(button[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //add panel to content pane

    add(panel);

    //display window

    setVisible(true);
}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        //determine which button is clicked
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
            {
                if (e.getSource() == button[i][j])
                {                       
                    //Check if the chosen button has already been picked.

                    if (checkerX[i][j] || checkerO[i][j])
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.");
                    }
                    else if (turn == 1 || turn == 3 || turn == 5 || turn == 7 || turn == 9)
                    {
                        button[i][j].setText("X");
                        checkerX[i][j] = true;
                        turn++;
                    }

                    //Checks all possible combinations for X to see if X won

                    if ((checkerX[0][0] == true && checkerX[0][4] == true && checkerX[0][5] == true) || (checkerX[1][0] == true && checkerX[1][6] == true && checkerX[1][7] == true) || (checkerX[2][0] == true                             && checkerX[2][8] == true && checkerX[2][9] == true) || (checkerX[0][0] == true && checkerX[1][0] == true && checkerX[2][0] == true) || (checkerX[0][10] == true && checkerX[1][11] == true                             && checkerX[2][12] == true) || (checkerX[0][13] == true && checkerX[1][14] == true && checkerX[2][15] == true) || (checkerX[0][0] == true && checkerX[1][16] == true && checkerX[2][17] ==                              true) || (checkerX[0][18] == true && checkerX[1][19] == true && checkerX[2][0] == true))
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X wins the game.");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }


                    //If X hasn't won, run the AI

                    runAI();

                    //If turn goes past 9, it means it's a tie

                    if (turn == 10)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It's a tie.");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void runAI()
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        boolean picked = false;
        if (turn == 2 || turn == 4 || turn == 6 || turn == 8)
        {
            while (picked == false)
            {
                int position1 = generator.nextInt(3);
                int position2 = generator.nextInt(3);

                //If the position is already picked, the AI will roll a random number again.

                if (checkerX[position1][position2] || checkerO[position1][position2])
                {

                }

                //If the position is empty, put an O.

                else
                {
                    button[position1][position2].setText("O");
                    checkerO[position1][position2] = true;
                    turn++;
                    picked = true;
                }
            }

        }

        //Checks all possible combinations for O to see if O won

        if ((checkerO[0][0] == true && checkerO[0][20] == true && checkerO[0][21] == true) || (checkerO[1][0] == true && checkerO[1][22] == true && checkerO[1][23] == true) || (checkerO[2][0] == true                    && checkerO[2][24] == true && checkerO[2][25] == true) || (checkerO[0][0] == true && checkerO[1][0] == true && checkerO[2][0] == true) || (checkerO[0][26] == true && checkerO[1][27] == true                   && checkerO[2][28] == true) || (checkerO[0][29] == true && checkerO[1][30] == true && checkerO[2][31] == true) || (checkerO[0][0] == true && checkerO[1][32] == true && checkerO[2][33] ==                          true) || (checkerO[0][34] == true && checkerO[1][35] == true && checkerO[2][0] == true))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O wins the game.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}


public static void main (String [] args)
{
    TicTacToe ttt = new TicTacToe();
}
}
```

There was a bit of a formatting problem when I tried to paste this on here so there might be some typos in the code. But the program actually runs as a .exe file.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Minigames for All</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h2 id="header">Welcome to Minigames for All.</h2>
    <hr>


    <object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550">
        <param name="code" value="TicTacToe" />
        <param name="archive" value="applet/TicTacToe.jar" />
        Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
    </object>

    <hr>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="rps.html">Rock, Paper, Scissors</td>
                <td><a href="random.html">Guess the Number</td>
                <td><a href="ttt.html">Tic Tac Toe</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td><a href="flip.html">Flip a Coin</td>
                <td><a href="rpg.html">Slime RPG</td>
                <td><a href="shoot.html">Space Shooter</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp</td>
                <td><a href="index.html">Home Page</td>
                <td>&nbsp</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Manifest file:

Manifest-Version: 1.0

Created-By: 1.7.0_21 (Oracle Corporation)

Error Message:http://puu.sh/5J4z1.png

Comment: Please show the HTML you're using, the jar file manifest, and the *exact* error.

Comment: Added more information regarding the error, html and manifest.

Comment: The error message has a "details" button - did you click on it?

Comment: Yes, the Java console that shows up in that error message is what shows up when I press details.

Comment: Since you already have a `JFrame`, it would make more sense to launch it from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I notice is this

```
TicTacToe extends JFrame
```

not

```
 TicTacToe extends JApplet // or even Applet.
```

Are you sure you have an [Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html)?

Comment: Not really sure about that... I originally created the program as an .java file. Is there a difference in code when making it as an applet?

Comment: @user3068063: Yes, you have to create a class which extends `Applet` or `JApplet`... fundamentally you *don't* have an applet at the moment.

Comment: @user3068063 At the moment you have a stand-alone Java application. A Java [Applet](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) refers to a specific kind of Java application, one that is not stand-alone, but rather runs in the context of an "Applet" container (which is [usually](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html) a web browser).

Comment: I see now. Thanks alot to both of you. Managed to get it working.